# Aggregate SQL query to summarize group payments

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I have a simple app used to track group payments. The database structure is like so:

[image]

Essentially, when you add a payment it is inserted into the `payments` table and the `payers_payments` join table contains pivot data concerning the amount each `payer` paid and whether they should be included in the payment. My app retrieves this data and builds a statement showing the amount each payer has paid, their fair share and the amount they owe. This is shown by payment and the amounts summed to give a total for each payer.

Example data:

**payer_payments**

[image]

**payments**

[image]

Here's an example statement with 2 payments (*data does not match the example data above*). In the second payment Tom is not included in the payment (`pays = false`) so his fair share is 0 and Tim's fair share is the sum of both their payments divided by the number of `pays=true` for that payment.

[image]

Is there a way to query the totals for each payer without getting each payment individually and looping through them to get a total? I can easily get the total paid for each payer:

```
SELECT payers_payments.payer_id, 
       Sum(payers_payments.amount) AS SumOfamount
  FROM payers_payments
GROUP BY 
       payers_payments.payer_id;
```

But how to get the fair share? Basically I need to sum the amount for each payment and divide by the number of payers who have `pays=true` to get the fair share for the payment and add it to the payer's fair share total if they have `pay=true` for that payment. Is this possible in 1 query?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle

Comment: sqlite but a generic solution is what I'm after. Next is to integrate with Laravel via eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT payers_payments.payer_id, 
       Sum(payers_payments.amount) AS SumOfamount,
       Sum(if(payers_payments.pays=1,1,0)) AS countOfPays
  FROM payers_payments
GROUP BY 
       payers_payments.payer_id;
```

That's MySQL version.

The sum(if()) could be replaced with

```
SUM(CASE(payers_payments.pays) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS countOfPays
```

Comment: This gets some of the way there - it says whether or not to add the `fair share` to the payer's total. But it doesn't calculate what the fair share for the payment is. I.e. the sum of all the `amounts` for that payment id divided by the count of `pays=true` for that payment id.

Comment: SumOfamount/countOfPays

Comment: That doesn't to it as `SumOfamount` is not the fair share, it is the total the payer has paid in all of his payments. To get the total amount for a given payment you need to sum the amount each payer paid towards it. E.g. in my example data `payment_id` 1: payer 1 paid 20 and payer 2 paid 23. Only payer 2 `pays` so `fairShare = (20+23) / countOfPays (1 for this payment) = 43`.

Comment: I think a join or sub-query is needed

Comment: Sum(if(payers_payments.pays=1,payers_payments.amount,0)) AS countOfPays

Comment: Again, this isn't right as it just sums what that payer paid, not the fair share for that payment. fair share = `SELECT sum(payers_payments.amount) / sum(payers_payments.pays) GROUP BY payers_payments.payment_id`

Comment: Ok, read all the combibation in the fields. Place the query into from section of anothe query select ... from (the select above) raw_data and use fullSum/payedSum

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain in a bit more detail?